HTMX get request within form includes select element name attribute in query string. Is there a way to avoid that?
Using Go html/templates, HTMX, Alpinejs
What i'm trying to accomplish is that when I select server name from a dropdown list I populate the database dropdown list with databases related to that instance. Using HTMX to get that database list the select element attribute name is added to the query string.
/getDatabases?database-name=&serverName=xxxxxx
Here is the code
<div>
    <label for="server-instance">Server Instance: 
        <span x-text="selectedServerInstance"></span>
    </label>
    <select id="server-instance" name="server-instance" x-model="selectedServerInstance">
        <option value="">Select a server instance</option>
        {{range .}}
        <option value="{{.ServerName}}">{{.ServerName}}</option>
        {{end}}
    </select>
</div>
<div x-cloak x-show="selectedServerInstance">
    <label for="database-name"></label>
    <select id="database-name" name="database-name" 
    hx-get="/getDatabases"
    :hx-vals="JSON.stringify({ serverName: selectedServerInstance })"
    hx-trigger="change from:#server-instance" 
    hx-target="#database-list" 
    hx-swap="outerHTML">
        <option value="">Select a database</option>
        <option id="database-list"></option>
    </select>
</div>

This code block is within a <form>
If I remove the name attribute than of course the query parameter is not added and I can not get the form value in my handler.
databaseName := c.FormValue("database-name")
When submitting the form i need to get what is selected for the database name so i can not remove that I just don't want to have this in my query when I get the list of databases.
Probably just some basic HTMX functionality, just not finding it in the documentation
Here is the full form. Requested in comment.
<div x-data="{ selectedServerInstance: '' }">
    <h2>Priviledges</h2>
    <form 
    hx-post="/submitUserPriviledgesForm" 
    hx-trigger="submit" 
    hx-target="#user-priviledge-container" 
    hx-swap="innerHTML">
        <div class="mb-4">
            <label for="username">Username:</label>
            <input type="text" id="username" name="username">
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="server-instance">Server Instance: <span x-text="selectedServerInstance"></span></label>
            <select id="server-instance" name="server-instance" 
            x-model="selectedServerInstance"
            x-on:change="document.querySelector('body').dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('serverInstanceChanged'))" >
                <option value="">Select a server instance</option>
                {{range .}}
                <option value="{{.ServerName}}">{{.ServerName}}</option>
                {{end}}
            </select>
        </div>
        <div x-cloak x-show="selectedServerInstance">
            <label for="database-name">(Optional)</span></label>
            <select id="database-name" name="database-name" 
            hx-get="/getDatabases"
            :hx-vals="JSON.stringify({ serverName: selectedServerInstance })"
            hx-trigger="serverInstanceChanged from:body" 
            hx-target="#database-list" 
            hx-swap="outerHTML">
                <option id="database-list"></option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div">
            <label for="skip-object-permission">Skip Object Permission:</label>
            <input type="checkbox" id="skip-object-permission" name="skip-object-permission">
        </div>
        <div>
            <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
<div>
    <div id="user-priviledge-container"></div>
</div>


I don't think this is possible, also I feel like it makes things more compliacted the way you're trying to populate the options. You should instead set the trigger on the server-instance and return the whole database-list field with prepoplated options from the backend. I'm not sure if it would play nice with alpine though. Can you please provide the full html includeing form and submit button?

If it would really be problematic (and I don't really think it is, it is just a little ugly the way it works now), I would probably put the server-instance select outside of the form and put a hidden input field with the server-instance inside the form. Then you get the best of both worlds.

I forgot to mention that this is assuming you would make the changes that mariodev suggests and let the server-instance select trigger changes.

Thanks for the answers. It might make sense like you mentioned @mariodev to have the trigger on the server-instance on option change to pull the data from the server and populate the database options. Probably more clean.

Thanks guys ( @mariodev @Gimby ). This is much cleaner this way. Moving the hx-get to the server-instance part also enables that I don't need to have a custom event to trigger pulling the database list. Just listen to change event within the select element.
Here is the form after changes:
<div x-data="{ selectedServerInstance: '' }">
    <h2>User Priviledges</h2>
    <form 
    hx-post="/submitUserPriviledgesForm" 
    hx-trigger="submit" 
    hx-target="#user-priviledge-container" 
    hx-swap="innerHTML">
        <div>
            <label for="username">Username:</label>
            <input type="text" id="username" name="username">
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="server-instance" class="block text-gray-700">Server Instance: <span>(Optional)</span></label>
            <select id="server-instance" name="server-instance" 
            x-model="selectedServerInstance"
            hx-get="/getDatabases"
            hx-trigger="change" 
            hx-target="#database-list-container" 
            hx-swap="innerHTML">
                <option value="">Select a server instance.</option>
                {{range .}}
                <option value="{{.ServerName}}">{{.ServerName}}</option>
                {{end}}
            </select>
        </div>
        <div x-cloak x-show="selectedServerInstance">
            <label for="database-name">Database: <span>(Optional)</span></label>
            <select id="database-list-container" name="database-name"></select>
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="skip-object-permission">Skip Object Permission:</label>
            <input type="checkbox" id="skip-object-permission" name="skip-object-permission">
        </div>
        <div>
            <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
<div>
    <div id="user-priviledge-container"></div>
</div>


This is the expected behaviour with a GET request, it will append form-enclosed input elements (with a name attribute) as query parameters. To avoid this, you could use a POST request instead.
